# MarkLogic 8 - XQuery - cts query to find document property by value

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way to find documents with a specific property value in the [document properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties)?

Follow-up question, are the document properties indexed?

(Properties meaning the `xdmp:document-add-properties()` kind)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap arbitrary queries in [`cts:properties-fragment-query()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:properties-fragment-query) to scope those queries to match only document properties. And, yes, [document properties are indexed](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/concepts/indexing#id_10367).

Comment: …but you’re usually better off avoiding properties fragments altogether. Anything that queries across a document fragment and its associated properties fragment requires a join at runtime. Joins aren’t free. Rather than storing related metadata in a separate (properties) fragment, wrap the properties in a subsection of the main document to avoid the runtime join. The exception, of course, is binary document fragments, which can’t hold XML or JSON content.